# Push notification with non-public image

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way of adding a non-public image, i.e. one at a URL that requires authentication, to a push notification? From what I've read you can only supply an image URL in the notification payload, and that URL is fetched by the OS (Android/iOS), not the associated app.

If it isn't possible, does anyone know of a best practice workaround? A time-limited URL was one thing that sprung to mind.

Using FCM.

I'm not the developer on this issue btw (or a mobile dev in any sense), just asking as an interested party.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I read it as you are using firebase storage, if you are:

In firebase storage, you can see to the right of a selected image, under the preview, a drop down called 'file location' here you can see storage location and an access token. If you click the access token it will copy a link with the access token.

This should be sufficient for the task

Comment: Thanks, but the image being accessed is not in Firebase storage.